# How to align two different font-sizes next to each other?

Tags: html, css

How do I align two different-sized fonts next to each other so that the smaller text is centered vertically with the larger text?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="parent">
    <span id="first">first</span>
    <span id="second">second</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first {
    font-size: 200%;   
}

#second {
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/BmbWr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `vertical-align: middle` property

http://jsfiddle.net/BmbWr/1/

Comment: Well I got a downvote. If someone can clue me in to why I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height css property. Set both first and second with the same line height.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
#first {
  font-size: 200%;
```

}

```
#second {
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:38px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/BmbWr/5/

I added one for further example.

Comment: When posting answers please include your code. Fiddles don't last forever and we want others to benefit from your knowledge.